# Proving a Subspace is a Subset

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and $U, W_1, W_2$, 3 subspaces of $V$ with $U \subseteq W_1 \cup W_2$. Show that $U \subseteq W_1$ or $U \subseteq W_2$.

Suppose $U \not \subseteq W_1$. Then, there exists $u \in U$ such that $u \not \in W_1$. Since $U \subseteq W_1 \cup W_2$, we have $u \in W_1 \cup W_2$, which means $u \in W_1$ or $u \in W_2$. Since $u \not \in W_1$, we must have $u \in W_2$. Now let $v \in U \cap W_1$. I'm not sure on how to show $v \in W_2$ however. I'd greatly appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> Definition of vector space. If $u,v \in U$ then $u+v \in U$.

The answer:

> Since $u,v \in U$ so $u+v\in U$ or $u+v \in W_1 \cup W_2$. And since $u \not\in W_1,v\in W_1$ so that means $u+v\in W_2$. Since $u \in W_2$ so $v \in W_2$.